Symfony process component and test environment
Problem: I need to run command in test environment, so I found to use symfony/process component.
Then I tried to run process in this way:
public function testProblem(): void
{
    $user = $this->proxyReferenceRepository->getReference('user_' . 1);

    $process = new Process(
        command: [
            'bin/console',
            'test:some-command',
            sprintf('--userId=%s', $user->getId()),
            '--env=test',
        ],
    );

    $process->start();

    $process->wait();

    dump($process->getOutput());
}

This does not work - the command runs without APP_ENV=test (it shows dump of APP_ENV and _em connection's db name - it is without _test suffix)
So  the next step was to try this way:
public function testProblem(): void
{
    $user = $this->proxyReferenceRepository->getReference('user_' . 1);

    $process = new Process(
        command: [
            'bin/console',
            'test:some-command',
            sprintf('--userId=%s', $user->getId()),
            '--env=test',
        ],
        env: ['APP_ENV' => 'test'],
    );

    $process->start();

    $process->wait();

    dump($process->getOutput());
}

In that case - the command already dumps APP_ENV=test, but the db connection is still default - without _test suffix.
So I tried to run this command directly from console - bin/console test:some-command --userId=2 --env=test to check possibility of working in test environment AND it is working!
But how to run the test env with the process component?
I also use a dama_bundle to run tests.
Maybe somebody met the problem before?
